# Regex not matching the pattern with spaces and new lines

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get from a string `Passed, <strong class="has_warnings">2 warning(s)</strong>`. I am a noob in regex please help.

```
$str_html = '
<td colspan="2" class="valid">
    Passed, <strong class="has_warnings">2 warning(s)</strong>   
</td> '

preg_match('#<td colspan="2" class="valid">(.*?)</td>#', $str_html, $data_html_errors);
```

The live non-formatted regex can be found here.

http://regexr.com/39e45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use any capturing groups.

```
<td colspan="2" class="valid">\s*\K.*?(?=\s+<\/td)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/33)

Comment: capturing groups may slow down your process.

Comment: Yes this is fast, 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex must be like this:

```
/<td colspan="2" class="valid">([\s\S]*)<\/td>/
```

Your original Regex has a few mistakes:

- The `.` does not match tabulators, line breaks, but your string contains them.
- The `?` is unnecessary. If you wanted the content in the `td` to be optional, the `*` already means 0 or more

http://regexr.com/39e48

This RegEx is probably more efficient:

```
/<td colspan="2" class="valid">(((?!<\/td>)[\s\S])+)<\/td>/
```

http://regexr.com/39e4n

Comment: There is a strange thing happening I am pulling up data with ajax, and when I added this regex, it loaded in 30 secs, it regex that performance expensive?

Comment: @user3467855 If you have a really big file *this* regex is very expensive. How big is your file? I'll try to provide you a better suited regex.

Comment: It's usually a web page so maybe between 10000 chars and 100000 chars.

Comment: Now it's echoing more than it should (though it's much faster) http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=checkprg.com I am trying to get the result from there. It is echoing actuqally starting from `<td colspan="2" class="valid">` and until the end of the string

Comment: With the first regex that you have written I was getting 36 secs, with this one 20 secs, is there anyway could be faster than this? Your time and persistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
 <td[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/td>
```

Try this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/29